# d3.js: Relative complement in TopoJSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I use [Natural Earth data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) to build a svg world map. Now I started to modify data to meet our customer‘s needs (on CLI). What I‘m stuck with is **subtracting** features in TopoJSON. I know how to use [topomerge](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#topomerge) two join two features but how to achieve the opposite?

To make it clear, upstream data provides

- a country A **including** a disputed area B
- the disputed area B in a different dataset

The desired result is country A *without* disputed area B, i.e `A-B` or the [*relative complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) of B in A.

Comment: Well, nobody seems to have an idea. Looking at set theory this could be solved by `A∖B  = ∁(∁A∪B)` or in words: The (absolute) complement of the union of absolute complement of A and B. Absolute complement would mean whole earth‘s surface with a hole in the shape of the country :-)